How to add an active class to a link that has a singular form of a slug within a loop
I had this in my settings.yml
menu :

      - {name: 'Blogs', url: 'blogs'}
      - {name: 'Work',  url: 'work'}
      - {name: 'Books', url: 'books'}
      - {name: 'Projects', url: 'projects'}
      - {name: 'Journal', url: 'journals'}

and so I looped it out in my html
  <nav class="nav-links">
           
          {% for item in site.data.settings.menu %}
        <li style="  list-style-type: none;" {% if navigation.url == item.url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
         <a href="{{ site.github.url }}/{{ item.url }}" class="nav-item">
                              {{ item.name }} 
         </a>
        </li>
            {% endfor %} 

              </nav>

But what if I want to also add an active class to the Blogs link that starts with '/blog/' url because I have a page that also shows my blog which is the link is like /blog/blue-sky not  /blogs/blue-sky
In the /blogs url I show all the blogs but in the /blog/*/ url  only a single blog is shown.
I want that Blogs menu <a> link to be highlighted also when I'm on /blog/** page.
Anyone capable of answering my question?

No time to look into it but one strategy to try is to put an if statement testing whether the current URL contains /blog/

this helped me, I hope it would help future developers.
 {% for item in site.data.settings.menu %}
            {% assign current = nil %} 

         {% assign url = item.url %}

      {% if page.url contains item.url %} 
           {% assign active = 'text-highlight' %} 
         {% endif %}
      
         <a 
          href="{{ site.github.url }}/{{ url }}" class="{% if forloop.first %}first{% endif %} {{ active }} {% if forloop.last %}last{% endif %} navLink">
                    {{ item.name }} 
                  </a>

      {% endfor %} 

menu :
  - { name: 'Blogs', url: 'blogs'}
  - { name: 'Work',  url: 'work'}
....

